# How to record combo box values using Macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

In an existing Excel spreadsheet, I am creating a macro to autofill rows based on what is entered in the first row. There are going to be 7 rows in all based on days of the week. So far I am successful in doing rest of the fields, however one cell is having a combobox with values.

```
Sunday=1
Monday=2
Tuesday=3
Wednesday=4
Thursday=5
Friday=6
Saturday=7
```

Each row has to get one of each value. I record these values one by one when I record Macro, but when I run Macro with click of button, it does not create these values. Any suggestions? 
BTW, in absence of combobox, I can create these values in other cells and copy then in this column via macro, but when I use combo box I am not being able to do so.

Here is the VBA generated by Macro:

```
Sub AList()
'
' AList Macro
'

'
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A4:A10"), Type:=xlFillCopy
    Range("A4:A10").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B4:B10"), Type:=xlFillCopy
    Range("B4:B10").Select
    Range("C4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C4:C10"), Type:=xlFillCopy
    Range("C4:C10").Select
    Range("E4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E4:E10"), Type:=xlFillCopy
    Range("E4:E10").Select
    Range("D10").Select
End Sub
```

Col D, which has the Days of week in Combobox, as previously listed is not recorded.
Please guide if and how I need to modify this vba code.

Comment: Can you just use a formula to determine the day of the week?

Comment: This indicates something's wrong with your code, doesn't it? So please add it to your post if you want assistance. Based only on the current information you've provided, it is practically impossible to tell exactly why your macro is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Edited my answer and tested the code below.  Seems to work:

```
Sub AList()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim days(1 To 7) As Variant

    days(1) = "Sunday"
    days(2) = "Monday"
    days(3) = "Tuesday"
    days(4) = "Wednesday"
    days(5) = "Thursday"
    days(6) = "Friday"
    days(7) = "Saturday"

    Range("A4:A10").Value = Range("A4").Value
    Range("B4:B10").Value = Range("B4").Value
    Range("C4:C10").Value = Range("C4").Value

    x = 1
    For Each c In Range("D4:D10")
        c.Value = days(x)
        x = x + 1
    Next c

    Range("E4:E10").Value = Range("E4").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: the code worked beautifully except for in column D it just added weekdays and the for loop didn't add numbers. But I could get around by changing to days(1) = "Sunday+1" and so on. Thanks